# How do I reverse the speed control on my ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan has a speed control wall switch that slides from Off->1->2->3-4 corresponding to different speeds. However for some reason 1 is the fastest speed and 4 is the slowest speed. I'm guessing it was wired incorrectly. Is this something I can fix in a straightforward way myself?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a technical reason why many fans are Off->High->Medium->Low instead of the seemingly more logical Off->Low->Medium->High.

The short answer is: motors need something special to get started, and doing that on the high-speed setting is more reliable.

For the long answer, [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ3GW7lVBWY).

As to whether it is *possible* to change it, that depends on the design of the switch. A possible "maybe".

Comment: Think it might also be do to the size of the diameter of the fan blades.  20 inch box fan is high to low, while 10 or 12 inch fans are low to high.